# User to access only to specific IP addresses

Tags: proxy, firewall, ufw, ip

How can I setup Ubuntu box so logged user can access only to several IP addresses, on all protocols?

Additional problem is that Ubuntu uses proxy to acceess to internet.

Tried with UFW, but did not manage with it (probably because pf proxy?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TO BLOCK A WEBSITE:

You can edit your host file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/hosts
```

add the websites you want to block:

```
0.0.0.1 www.yoursite.com
```

It works with all browsers I guess.

TO ALLOW ONLY ONE WEBSITE:

and to only allow access to one ip adress try:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d {type here the ip} --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REJECT
```

See! it's easy ;)

Comment: tnx :-) will it work if my ubuntu uses proxy?

Comment: try it and leave us a response to know please :)